# 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'WCHAR *' to 'const char *

Tags: c++, char, constants, strcpy, wchar

Having some issues with strcpy...

Getting this error:

`strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'WCHAR *' to 'const char *`

Here is the code...

```
char FunctionName[ 256 ]; 
UFunction *pUFunc                        = NULL;
strcpy( FunctionName, pUFunc->GetFullName() );
```

And also:

```
WCHAR* UObject::GetFullName ()
{
    if ( this->Class && this->Outer )
    {
        static WCHAR ObjectName[ 256 ];

        if (Outer == NULL)
        {
            wsprintf(ObjectName, L"");
        }
        else
        {
            if (Outer->Outer)
                wsprintf(ObjectName, L"%s %s.%s.%s", Class->Name.GetName(), Outer->Outer->Name.GetName(), Outer->Name.GetName(), Name.GetName());
            else if(Outer)
                wsprintf(ObjectName, L"%s %s.%s", Class->Name.GetName(), Outer->Name.GetName(), Name.GetName());
        }
        return ObjectName;
    }

    return L"(null)";
}
```

Comment: The error message, in this case, is pretty much clear -- `strcpy`  simply doesn't deal with wide C-style strings. Furthermore, it doesn't really make sense to try and store on in an ordinary C-style string.

Comment: Note that both `strcpy()` and `wcscpy()` are for copying strings, not for converting strings.  You need a different (non-standard) function to convert between plain `char` and `WCHAR`.

Comment: Your code is very confusing. You are accessing a member of an object pointer you have explicitly set to NULL beforehand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need wcscpy for WCHAR items, not strcpy. But the real problem is that you are trying to convert a wide string to a narrow string. `WideCharToMultiByte` since you seem to be on Windows.

Comment: I tried that...

'wcscpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [256]' to 'wchar_t *'

Comment: @E3pO: obviously both parameters need to be of type `wchar_t *`, so you have to convert your ASCII string to unicode first

Comment: @Niklas his target is narrow, so he is really trying to convert the wide result of the function to the narrow string.

Comment: @bmargulies: Maybe it's the other way round and his target should be wide. We can only assume, but converting from unicode to ASCII is not possible in the general case. **EDIT:** So your guess was better :)

Comment: This is great!!!! I changed my project from Unicode to Multi-Byte and it works!!!!. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious from the error: strcpy expects `const char*` as the second parameter and you are passing `WCHAR*`